# How do we change the numeric form of OIDs into human readable form

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, mib

How do we change the numeric form of Private MIB OIDs into human readable form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MIB Browsers can help translate among different forms, such as

http://www.mg-soft.si/mgMibBrowserPE.html

There are also free command line tools, such as

http://www.net-snmp.org/tutorial/tutorial-5/commands/snmptranslate.html

But human readable form is only useful for human. Network devices still talk in numeric form only.

Comment: How did you talk to that device then? Using what kind of tools? A typical tool requires you to import the private MIB documents and then you can use human readable form in it.

Comment: Hi Li .....Thanks......actually what I want is that whatever OID m going to use to get the information should be in human-readable form ...For Ex.--In MIB-2 we can use sysdescr.0....same thing I want for private device like ZyXel ...for getting their private MIB information from the device I have to give the complete OID like 1.3.6.1.4.1.890.1.5.8.19.1.7.0
actually its for sysSwYear,but whenever I tried to use it as sysSwYear it throws an error like ----"sysSwYear.0: Unknown Object Identifier (Sub-id not found: (top) -> sysSwYear)
"  ...What should I do

Comment: m using Net-SNMP on Fedora -14....Through CLI only by using SNMP-Walk or SnmpGet command

Comment: Learn about where net-snmp stores its MIB documents, and copy the private ones there. Or you can learn which command line switch allows you to specify your document folder.

Comment: actually whatever u told ,that I already had done...but not getting the result....is their any thing which I need to be restart or recompile...sorry but the problem is m very new to this

Comment: If you have done that, try to use snmptranslate to first convert from numerical form to human readable form. That should give you some idea on what is the correct form net-snmp expects.

Comment: Hi Lex Li, I am struggling very much to find out that why hostname keeps coming as <UNKNOWN> in SNMP-Trap v2...Will u please help me out to rectify this problem..I shall be highly thankful to you...Please help me out.Here is the trap example--<UNKNOWN> UDP: [192.168.1.150]:1028->[192.168.1.23] .iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2.system.sysUpTime.sysUpTimeInstance 0:0:01:07.00 .iso.org.dod.internet.snmpV2.snmpModules.snmpMIB.snmpMIBObjects.snmpTrap.snmpTra‌​pOID.0 .iso.org.dod.internet.snmpV2.snmpModules.snmpMIB.snmpMIBObjects.snmpTraps.linkDo‌​wn

Comment: It is nothing strange. If you cannot translate an IP address to a host name, of course <UNKNOWN> should be returned. Please learn about DNS protocol.